# Rename files in Mac OS

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have written code which reads file names from column A and renames it to column B, if file specified in column A exists in Input folder.

```
Sub Rename_click()
    Dim inputFolder$, iFile$, oFile$
    Dim iRow&, lRow&

    inputFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Input"

    With shInput
        If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For iRow = 2 To lRow
            iFile = .Cells(iRow, "A")
            oFile = .Cells(iRow, "B")

            If iFile <> "" And oFile <> "" Then    
                If Dir(inputFolder & Application.PathSeparator & iFile) <> "" Then
                    Name inputFolder & Application.PathSeparator & iFile As inputFolder & Application.PathSeparator & oFile
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

It works in Windows. How can I make it Mac compatible?

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj614412(v=office.14).aspx) might be of some use.

Comment: Not sure Excel is the best tool for managing your filesystem with. I presume the `Name` function is where to start - try just using it on a single file first till you are sure it works.

Comment: [Ron de Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/section3.htm) appears to have a lot of experience with VBA on a Mac.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thans for but I don't see any rename file code there

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Do you have error messages, wrong behaviour, ...? Please edit your question accordingly.